# MNIST IOerror, Datasets aren't loading using Tensorflow without GPU support

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

I'm getting this error while running the MNIST programs.

This backup URL might be one solution but it isn't working for me.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/8171

python DeepMNIST.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "DeepMNIST.py", line 5, in <module>
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py", line 240, in read_data_sets
source_url + TRAIN_IMAGES)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py", line 208, in maybe_download
temp_file_name, _ = urlretrieve_with_retry(source_url)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py", line 165, in wrapped_fn
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py", line 190, in urlretrieve_with_retry
return urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 245, in retrieve
fp = self.open(url, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 213, in open
return getattr(self, name)(url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 443, in open_https
h.endheaders(data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1053, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 897, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 859, in send
self.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1278, in connect
server_hostname=server_hostname)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 353, in wrap_socket
_context=self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 601, in __init__
self.do_handshake()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 830, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
IOError: [Errno socket error] [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a socket error, has little to do with Tensorflow. The url it is trying to connect to is probably invalid.